# How to update a particular row of a vueJs array list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a proper way to refresh one particular row from a vueJS array list without reloading all the data?

In this case, it is a phone list.

```
<template>
    <table class="table">
        <tr v-for="phone in phones">
            <td @click="edit(phone.id)">
                {{phone.number}}
            </td>
            <td class="pointerCursor" @click="edit(phone.id)">
                {{phone.comment | truncate(90)}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                phones = [
                    {id:1, number: '001 656 88 44', comment:''},
                    {id:2, number: '610-910-3575 x2750', comment:'Quod odit quia'},
                    {id:3, number: '536.224.2639 x714', comment:'primary phone'},
                    {id:5, number: '0034 556 65 77', comment:'home phone phone'},
                ]
            }
        },

        methods: {
            edit(id) {
                // update using an api that returns the updated data.
                var updatedPhone = update(id)

                // how to update with reloading all the phone list?
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

PS: this is a code just to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const currentIndex = this.phones.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
this.phones.splice(currentIndex, 1, updatedPhone)
```

If your target environment doesn't support findIndex on arrays, you can use some other means of finding the current index. One would be pass the phone instead of it's id.

```
edit(phone) {
    const currentIndex = this.phones.indexOf(phone);

    // update using an api that returns the updated data.
    var updatedPhone = update(phone.id)

    this.phones.splice(currentIndex, 1, updatedPhone)
}
```

In both cases, Vue will detect the change and re-render for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the built-in index generation:

```
    <tr v-for="(phone, index) in phones">
        <td @click="edit(index)">
            {{phone.number}}
        </td>
        <td class="pointerCursor" @click="edit(index)">
            {{phone.comment | truncate(90)}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And then in your edit function:

```
    methods: {
        edit(index) {
            phone = this.phones[index];

            // update using an api that returns the updated data.
            var updatedPhone = update(phone.id)

            // how to update with reloading all the phone list?
            this.phones.splice(index, 1, updatedPhone)
        }
    }
```