# Splicing array does not re-render table row Vuejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a user table generated with data from an ajax request. Table roughly looks like this: [Image of Table][1]

When an admin edits a user's username, I want the user's row to re-render with the changes (specifically the users firstname and lastname).

I create the table fine. The models work fine. My parent component receives the edited data just fine in my edit() method, but I can't seem to make my target row re-rendered with my changed data. How can I make my target row update?

I tried the following and it didn't work:

- [How to update a particular row of a vueJs array list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284029/how-to-update-a-particular-row-of-a-vuejs-array-list)
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats
- I have set key to my row
- Tried setting my listOfUsers with Vue.set()
- Tried using Vue.set() in place of splice

Here is my parent vue component with the following (I took out irrelevant details):

TEMPLATE:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Stat</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(user, index) in listOfUsers" :key="'row' + user._id"> 
            <td>{{user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.created}}</td>
            <td>
                <a v-if="user.confirmed" @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'confirm')"></a>
                <a v-else @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'unconfirm')"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="buttonCase">
                <a @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'info')"></a>

                <a v-if="user.blocked" @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'blocked')"></a>
                <a v-else @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'block')"></a>
        
                <a v-if="user.enforce_info === 'required'" @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'enforceInfoActive')"></a> 
                <a v-else-if="user.enforce_info === 'done'" @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'enforceInfoChecked')"></a>
                <a v-else @click="determineButtonClicked(index, 'enforceInfo')"></a>

                <modal v-if="usersList[index]" @toggleClickedState="setState(index)" @editUser="edit(index, $event)" :id="user._id" :action="action"></modal>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
    export default {
        created: function() {
            let self = this;
            $.getJSON("/ListOfUsers",
            function(data){
                self.listOfUsers = data;
            });
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                listOfUsers: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            edit(index, update){
                let user = this.listOfUsers[index];
                user.firstName = update.firstName;
                user.lastName = update.lastName;
                
                // this.listOfUsers.splice(index, 1, user)
                this.listOfUsers.$set(index, user)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you for your time and help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYQ2A.png

Comment: What is `<modal>`? How does `$event` in `edit(index, $event)` become `update` in `edit(index, update) { ... }`?

Comment: @Phil <modal> is a vue component defined in another file. Just like its name, this component defines a modal pop up. The $event is how I access emitted values from my modal component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is not updating in your edit method because the object itself is not being replaced. Properties of the object do change, but Vue is only looking for the object reference to change.

To force the array to detect a change in the actual object reference, you want to replace the object, not modify it. I don't know exactly how you'd want to go about doing it, but this hacked together fiddle should demonstrate the problem so you can work around it: http://jsfiddle.net/tga50ry7/5/

In short, if you update your edit method to look like this, you should see the re-render happening in the template:

```
methods: {
   edit(index, update){
      let currentUser = this.listOfUsers[index];
      let newUser = {
         first_name: update.firstName,
         last_name: update.lastName,
         email: currentUser.email,
         created: currentUser.created
      }

      this.listOfUsers.splice(index, 1, newUser)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I used Object.assign() to get a copy of my object before making changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try like this

```js
<script>
    export default {
        created: function() {
            let self = this;
            $.getJSON("/ListOfUsers",
            function(data){
                self.listOfUsers = data;
            });
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                listOfUsers: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            edit(index, update){
                let user = this.listOfUsers[index];
                user.firstName = update.firstName;
                user.lastName = update.lastName;

                // this.listOfUsers.splice(index, 1, user)
                this.$set(this.listOfUsers,index, user)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```